# trying to get a sticky element with jquery waypoint

Tags: jquery, scroll, sticky

So I am trying to create a sticky div that either scrolls up the page or scrolls down the page (onClick) depending on where it is on the page.

I have been tweaking the code for some time and can't get the magic formula.

I am using plugins from: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started and http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

The code is here.

```
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/scripts/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/newlayout/script/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/newlayout/script/waypoints-sticky.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

...

```
<script>


$(function() {                     // When the page has loaded,
  $('.tabbycat').waypoint(               // create a waypoint
    function() {

        $('#tabtabtab').removeClass('tabbycat', 1, 'linear');
        $('#tabtabtab').addClass('stuck', 1, 'linear');


    }
  )
});

$(function() {                     // When the page has loaded,
  $('.top').waypoint(               // create a waypoint
    function() {

        $('#tabtabtab').removeClass('stuck', 1, 'linear');
        $('#tabtabtab').addClass('tabbycat', 1, 'linear');

    }
  )
});

var itsthis = document.getElementsByClassName('tabbycat');
var thistoo = document.getElementsByClassName('stuck');

$(itsthis).onClick(function(){
$(window).scrollTo( {top:'1px', left:'1px'}, 300 );
});


$(thistoo).onClick(function(){
$(window).scrollTo( {top:'339px', left:'1px'}, 300 );
});


</script>
```

Tally Ho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below plugin

http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.js

Check the demo also

http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the one Chetan said and I have to say, Stickyfloat refreshes each time you scroll, so there is a delay of milliseconds we can see (its very annoying when applying the script for backgrounds), so I preffer this one that makes the CSS attribute of the layer as Fixed once it gets up to the position height in which the layer is, so THERE IS NO REFRESH once you keep scrolling down.

http://stickyjs.com/

Only downside is that you can't stop the effect once you reach the parent bottom (if you need that). Maybe a tweak would make it.